# Mingw32 and blank spaces (building Qt 5.1 for android on windows)

Tags: qt, qt5, mingw32

Currently I am trying to build the alpha release of Qt 5.1 with Android support under Windows 7.

I followed the steps in this [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/wiki/building_qt-android_on_windows). Now I am at the point where I try to actually build Qt but I am facing the problem that mingw32-make has problems with paths containing blank spaces.

I just enter mingw32-make an it starts compiling. Somewhere in the middle there is the  output

```
     mingw32-make[4]: Entering directory 'c:/work/build/qt5/qtbase/src/tools/moc' g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,console -o ..\..\..\bin\moc.exe .obj/release_shared/moc.o .obj/release_shared/preprocessor.o .obj/release_shared/generator.o .obj/release_shared/parser.o .obj/release_shared/token.o .obj/release_shared/main.o 
-L"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\SDK\v1.1\Lib" -LC:/work/build/qt5/qtbase/lib -lQt5Bootstrap 
-LC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\SDK\v1.1\Lib -luser32 -lole32 -ladvapi32
    g++: error: Files\Microsoft: No such file or directory
    g++: error: Visual: No such file or directory
    g++: error: Studio: No such file or directory
    g++: error: .NET: No such file or directory
    g++: error: 2003\SDK\v1.1\Lib: No such file or directory
```

The problem is the last -L argument and the contained blank spaces (and missing quotes).

How do I get mingw32 to put the last -L argument under quotes too in order to compile Qt 5.1?

Found an solution: the missing quotes are in the src/tools/moc/make.debug & make.release. Also the qt5/config.summary contains this path. Adding the quotes manually lets me compile (although it stops due to a different error).

Comment: It's really odd that you have Visual Studio paths anywhere in the build if you're doing a mingw build... that's not supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Mingw give you a very clear warning not to include paths with spaces in:

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Specify_the_Location_of_External_Libraries_for_use_with_MinGW

(Search for "any directory with white space" on that page)

However I believe it uses the UNIX convention. Change your path from:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\SDK\v1.1\Lib"
```

to:

```
"C:/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ .NET\ 2003/SDK/v1.1/Lib"
```

And it might just work for you.

If not download Microsofts [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) tool and setup a junction without spaces in, pointing to that location and update your build script to point to the junction.